# can't change f.select to a check_box with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, has-many-through

Is it possible to generate multiple rows in the joined-model table using the new_form from exercise?
The code only works when creating a single exercise, that links to a body_section then selecting an existing muscle.

I tried to change the code to use check_box but failed

**Original Code**

exercise.model

```
  has_many :body_sections
  has_many :muscles, through: :body_sections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :body_sections
end
```

muscle.model

```
  has_many :body_sections
  has_many :exercises, through: :body_sections
```

body_section.model

```
  belongs_to :muscle
  belongs_to :exercise
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise
end
```

exercise controller

```
def new
  @exercise = Exercise.new
  @exercise.body_sections.build
  @muscles = Muscle.all
end

# private method for strong parameter 
  params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :note, :body_sections_attributes => [:name, :muscle_id])
```

**Modified for check_box**

exercise _form.view

```
<div>
  <%= exercise_form.label :name, "Exercise Name" %>
  <%= exercise_form.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div>
  <%= exercise_form.fields_for :body_sections do |body_form| %>
    <%= body_form.label :name, "Body Section Common Name" %>
    <%= body_form.text_field :name %>
    <br>
    <%= body_form.collection_check_boxes(:muscle_ids, @muscles, :id, :name) do |c| %>
      <%= c.label { c.check_box } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

exercise controller

```
# private method for strong parameter 
  params.require(:exercise).permit(:name, :note, :body_sections_attributes => [:name, :muscle_ids => []])
```

I get an undefined method `muscle_ids' error
apparently the body_section does not have muscle_ids methods belongs to it.   How should I modify the code to be able to use checkbox to select and create multiple rows in body_sections at the same time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One body section can only have one muscle associated to it.

I would use [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to have dynamic nested fields for adding/removing body sections.

And then instead of `collection_check_boxes :muscles_ids`, I would use `body_form.select options_from_collection(@muscles)`.

Would seem more logical to me that:

```
Exercise has many ExerciseMuscles
ExerciseMuscles belongs to Exercise
ExerciseMuscles belongs to Muscle
Muscle belongs to BodySection
BodySection has many muscles
```

This way, you create your muscles/body sections, and then people associate which muscles are used by the exercise in the form (that way you also have access to Exercise has many body sections (through muscles)).